# Python: Reshape 3D image series to pixel series

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

i have a 3D numpy array of images with the shape `(imageCount, width, height)`.

My goal is to transform this into a 2D pixel series array with the shape `(pixelPosition, imageCount)`.

Right now this is my solution:

```
timeSeries= []

for h in range(height):
    for w in range(width):
        timeSeries.append(images[:,h,w])
```

is there a simpler way with `numpy.reshape()` or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose and reshape -

```
images.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(height*width,-1)
```